# Java not creating the file

Tags: java

I have a program with the package name "appdb" then  i want to create the .txt file, it is compiling and running fine thus showing me that the file was created since i can't see it in the working directory where i expected it to be.

```java
package appdb;

import java.io.*;

public class CreateAndWrite{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            File myFile= new File("myFile.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myFile,true);

            writer.write("Write this in the file");
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you're running your code. I'd also suggest you start following Java naming conventions - where package names are in lower-case, but class names are in PascalCase.

Comment: @Fenio: I really don't expect that's the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you're right. I created a simple project with and without the package and I was able to create the file running the `main` method

Comment: I am able to run your code and the file is being created in both the cases.

The file will be created in the base folder of your project in both the cases.

Can you verify if the file not being created in the base folder when you are placing your class createAndWrite in the package AppDb?

Could you also share the project structure?

Comment: You need to call `myFile.createNewFile();`. This method will return true, if the file is being created or false, if it already exists.

Comment: @CodingTil No, he does *not* need to call `File.createNewFile()`. That creates a new file, deleting it if it already exists. only for `new FileWriter()` to find it, delete it *again*, and create *another* one. Total waste of time. And the reason for the failure is suppressed by `createNewFile()`.

Comment: What exception was thrown? It seems far more likely that your program didn't run at all, if the only change you made was to the package name. What command line did you use?

Comment: @swithencolaco The file will be created in the current working directory, whatever that is when the code is run. There may not even *be* a project, let alone a project directory, and if there is it may have nothing to do with the current working directory.

Comment: @user207421 From the documentation of `File.createNewFile()` "Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. ". It does *not* delete any file, ever.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the correction. It doesn't make much difference to my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I got the answer. The problem was that I was running and compiling the file from the parent folder "**javac appdb/CreateAndWrite.java**" so the file was created there thus I couldn't see it in the working directory. But I only changed the path of the file to be created ,before:**myFile.txt**,after: **appdb/myFile.txt** and things worked as I expected.